# Javascript and the IE back button

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, jquery

When the back button is pressed in Safari the javascript state of the previous page gets saved.  However in IE9 it doesn't seem to.  Is this one of those "just the way it is with IE" things or is there something I need to enable this?  The application is ASP.NET, javascript and ajax.

Comment: What do you mean by "JavaScript state"?

Comment: Is it a hashchange (window.onhashchange event)?

Comment: for example say you change a css class on a link via jquery it wont remember this when you go back to the page.

Comment: I'd say that IE9's behaviour is the "correct" one in this case. If not correct, then expected at least. The web is stateless - anything you want to be recreated when you revist a page must be recreated by the server.

Comment: My guess is that when you press back in IE9 it reloads the page, but when you press back in Safari, it restores the page to what you had when you left it.  So, to answer your question- it's just the way IE9 is.

Comment: IE9 will remember the state of html checkboxes but not the javascript so its in a weird in-between state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's just the way IE9 is. I guess there is hope for IE10.